# A improved StringBuffer - Java.Lang

Tags: java, stringbuffer

I wanted to create my own StringBuffer which has 2-3 more methods added to the java.lang.StringBuffer. Since the original class is final I cannot extend that class.

Now, If I copy paste the class into my own class, then it says 'AbstractStringBuilder is not visible' error.

How to extend this class in my own namespace (say com.util).

Comment: did you notice that StringBuffer has a `Copyright (c) 2006, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 * ORACLE PROPRIETARY/CONFIDENTIAL. Use is subject to license terms.`?

Comment: what methods you want to add? which class you are copy pasting?

Comment: @Denis -is that current ? OpenJDK StringBuilder appears to be GPLed (IANAL). http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/StringBuilder.java

Comment: @BrianAgnew: I'm still on jdk6, it has a proprietary license.

Comment: since you prefer the heads-on approach, I'd recommend getting OpenJDK source code here - http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7 and changing whatever classes you want. Then you can just build it and use your shiny new and improved java. But you would have to redistribute it along with your application and make any source changes freely available.

Comment: IMHO Making StringBuffer synchronized was not a good design choice and using StringBuilder is better, not just for performance but making it clear that it does not attempt to be thread safe.

Answer (score 6):

I would work with [StringBuilder rather than StringBuffer](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/08/stringbuilder-vs-stringbuffer.html).

It's unfortunate that you can't implement an interface representing `StringBuilder` (unless [Appendable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Appendable.html) is suitable?). Have you tried creating an `EnhancedStringBuilder` class that contains your `StringBuilder` as a member. You can then delegate most(all?) calls to this, and provide your own.

An alternative is to simply [take the OpenJDK source code for StringBuilder](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/StringBuilder.java) and repackage and enhance it. I think the licensing will permit this, but I'm not familiar with your circumstances and you should check this.

Comment: the licensing would require making whole application GPLv2 licensed.

Answer (score 6):

I would personally use the [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) for this - a class that wraps the original StringBuilder and then provides extra methods to use as appropriate.

If you only want to add a couple more methods, you may also want to look at just using equivalent static methods that do the job.

(As others have mentioned, StringBuilder is the better, more efficient choice over StringBuffer, unless you really need the thread safety the latter provides.)

Simply copying and pasting the code isn't a great idea, you're likely breaking licensing laws and duplicating functionality (even if that functionality is in the original API.)

Answer (score 5):

Potential licensing issues aside, I would not recommend copying and pasting the source code just to add a couple of methods. Instead, I'd suggest making those methods `static` and placing them into a helper class (call it `StringBuilderUtils` or something similar).

The methods would take an instance of `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` (or perhaps even [`Appendable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Appendable.html) if you can implement your functionality in terms of `Appendable`).

Comment: This does hinge on the required functionality being implementable via the public API. Worth noting

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the AbstractStringBuilder also. But I don't know the dependencies of that one. My recommendation is to create a Wrapper class to StringBuilder, and encapsulate it.

Don't worry about the performance, delegate calls can really easy be inlined into classes using your StringBuilderWrapper.